# Can Location pin marker for Google maps generate the neighborhood name?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We are developing a free classifieds website for real-estate. When the seller wants to add an ad for his/her real-estate at one stage, the Google maps will open then he/she should drop the pin to the exact property location on Google maps. Up to here it is easy.

The question is, can I get the neighborhood name or title of that location?

Is there an API for Google that gives the neighborhood for that location where I dropped the pin on Google maps?

Comment: It is called ["reverse geocoding"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) [example using it](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeB.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this sample: [Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

What you should do is call the `codeLatLng()` method when the marker is dropped on the map.

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pascal_/LhqW6/) based on the maps api documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot

The demo link you sent me works great in Europe and USA
It gives the neighborhood name exactly

But I am having problem with cities in the Middle East 
let us  go to a city in Saudi Arabia
Jeddah, Saudi Arabia for example 

The marker does not generate neighborhood name I really don’t know why!
Is there a way to solve such a problem?

Comment: If you look at the [api reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) you will see that you can get various result from the result array. I have modified the fiddle to show `results[0]` instead of `results[1]`. Take a look and let me know if this is what you need. Also, make sure you are at a low zoom level if you want it to work well.

Comment: Pascal that was great help

Comment: Pascal that was great help indeed
It is giving the district name in Saudi Arabia
But one last thing:
How would I get the results in Arabic? I mean the district name in Arabic language?
Do I have to use the Google map that has the Arabic interface? Then results will be in Arabic!

Comment: You can add the language when you load the API like this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&language=ar&sensor=false"></script>`. It's explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization)